# How make recursive json on mysql

Tags: mysql, json, hierarchy, recursive

my table looks like

```
CREATE TABLE `test_comments` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `test_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `comment` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `rate` mediumint(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `test_comments_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
  KEY `test_comments_test_id_foreign` (`test_id`),
  KEY `test_comments_parent_id_foreign` (`parent_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `test_comments_parent_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `test_comments` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `test_comments_test_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`test_id`) REFERENCES `tests` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `test_comments_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=27 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

how can i retrieve comments like this structure:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "comment": "...",
        "comments": [
            {
                "id": 12,
                "comment": "answer for #3",
                "comments": []
            },
            {
                "id": 14,
                "comment": "answer for #3",
                "comments": [
                    {
                        "id": 22,
                        "comment": "sub comment for #14",
                        "comments": [
                            {
                                "id": 23,
                                "comment": "discussion continues..."
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 44,
        "comment": "wow so many comments!",
        "comments": []
    }
]
```

I had an idea to form this structure in the application layer, but I think that this will negatively affect the memory consumption and the load as a whole.

I do not know how others solve such problems and i have not yet found a solution. I will be grateful if the community will tell me the right way :)

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 4):

## MySQL 8+

Using MySQL 8, you can write a Recursive Common Table Expression.

- [Recursive Common Table Expression Examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-examples)

The example under [Hierarchical Data Traversal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-hierarchy-traversal) is pretty much what you're looking for, what you call `parent_id` they call `manager_id`

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
  id         INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  name       VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  manager_id INT NULL,
  INDEX (manager_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (manager_id) REFERENCES employees (id)
);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES
(333, "Yasmina", NULL),  -- Yasmina is the CEO (manager_id is NULL)
(198, "John", 333),      -- John has ID 198 and reports to 333 (Yasmina)
(692, "Tarek", 333),
(29, "Pedro", 198),
(4610, "Sarah", 29),
(72, "Pierre", 29),
(123, "Adil", 692);

WITH RECURSIVE employee_paths (id, name, path) AS
(
  SELECT id, name, CAST(id AS CHAR(200))
    FROM employees
    WHERE manager_id IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT e.id, e.name, CONCAT(ep.path, ',', e.id)
    FROM employee_paths AS ep JOIN employees AS e
      ON ep.id = e.manager_id
)
SELECT *
FROM employee_paths
ORDER BY path;

+------+---------+-----------------+
| id   | name    | path            |
+------+---------+-----------------+
|  333 | Yasmina | 333             |
|  198 | John    | 333,198         |
|   29 | Pedro   | 333,198,29      |
| 4610 | Sarah   | 333,198,29,4610 |
|   72 | Pierre  | 333,198,29,72   |
|  692 | Tarek   | 333,692         |
|  123 | Adil    | 333,692,123     |
+------+---------+-----------------+
```

The docs even explain it,

> How the CTE works:
>
> - The nonrecursive SELECT produces the row for the CEO (the row with a
>     NULL manager ID).
> - The path column is widened to CHAR(200) to ensure that there is room
>     for the longer path values produced by the recursive SELECT.
> - Each row produced by the recursive SELECT finds all employees who
>     report directly to an employee produced by a previous row. For each
>     such employee, the row includes the employee ID and name, and the
>     employee management chain. The chain is the manager's chain, with the
>     employee ID added to the end.
> - Recursion ends when employees have no others who report to them.

They further have an example wuth specific employee or employees, for more information see [*"Hierarchical Data Traversal"* with MySQL 8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-hierarchy-traversal)